# Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{' JSON

Tags: json, kubernetes-helm

Could someone explain, what it does not like in my HELM json file?

File:

```
{{- if .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ include "kuard.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "kuard.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ include "kuard.fullname" . }}
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas }}
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.autoscaling.maxReplicas }}
  metrics:
    {{- if .Values.autoscaling.targetCPUUtilizationPercentage }}
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: {{ .Values.autoscaling.targetCPUUtilizationPercentage }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if .Values.autoscaling.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage }}
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        targetAverageUtilization: {{ .Values.autoscaling.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

OUTPUT:
It says that Parse error on first line:

```
        Error: Parse error on line 1:
    {   {       -       if.Values.au
    --^
    Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'
```

Comment: What command are you running that produces that error?  The Helm template files can approximately only be used with Helm (they run a Go-based templating system and produce YAML as output); they are not JSON files.